# How to connect TWO android devices to a pc via USB

Tags: sockets, connection, usb, client-server, adb

I wrote an app which runs on two android tablets at the same time. The app enables both devices to communicate with a java server which is running on the pc, via WLAN socket communication. 
The problem with the WLAN connection is that it doesn't always seem to be reliable. So I wanted to setup a socket communication to the server via USB cables.

My problem no is how to connect TWO android devices to the server via USB cables. I found this tutorial for connecting ONE device to the server via ADB, but I see no possibility using this approach for two devices:
http://www.anothem.net/archives/2010/10/15/android-usb-connection-to-pc/

Has anyone an idea how to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest using ethernet instead of USB.

Answer (score 0):

If your tablet is runs ICS or newer Android OS, then it is very likely that it has OTG capable micro-USB socket, and you can add a USB-Ethernet dongle, and then connect the 2 tablets to your PC over ethernet, instead of USB. This, might be the most elegant solution.

Of course, you'd need a switch (or hub) to connect them together. Also note that, not all USB-Ethernet dongles may work out-of-the-box. You might have to experiment with few models, especially the el-cheapo ones to get them to work.